# Word 2013: On a multiple column page, append endnotes at end of last column

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

in Word 2007+, on a page with multiple columns, I would like to have the details of the footnotes/endnotes to appear at the end of the last column, instead of at the bottom of the page.

See picture: http://a47i.img-up.net/footnoteb2f5.png

I have tried to set the position of the endnotes at "end of section" and add a continuous section break right after the last character in the right column. but the endnotes still appear as in the left panel.

Any way of achieving this?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

converting footnotes to endnotes doesn't solve the problem in Word 2013, see picture:
http://q70.img-up.net/columnae72.png

creating the document in 2007 (with desired endnote position) and then opening it in 2013 works, but only in compatibility mode; if you "save as" it as another file, word will warn you that "some minor layout changes are possible" which unfortunately includes the positioning of the endnotes.

any fixes/workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

In my Word 2010, using an endnote instead of a footnote (note there is a difference between endnotes and footnotes) worked to put the note where you specify. If you already have footnotes, you can convert them to endnotes by the instructions here (pdf) http://www.staffs.ac.uk/assets/ins110_footnotes_Wd2007_tcm68-27497_tcm44-38431.pdf

Comment: thanks darthbith, i found out that indeed, it works as you say in 2010 but in 2013, they changed it.